# How to change code on live Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I have a site deployed on server and I'm accessing it with putty with hostIP and an RSA key.

How can I update the code on the deployed site? If the code is modified, do we have to rebuild (or run) the code?

Comment: you don't have to run the code. You just have to refresh the page after making changes

Comment: you should not change code on-the-fly but if you still want to.. you can edit your code with your favorite terminal editor (vi/vim/nano/etc..), change your code and then restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the code using editor (vim, nano, or whatever), then restart your web server. But that's not the right way to do it. You should edit it in your local machine, and use a deployment tool like Capistrano. See below.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-ruby-on-rails-application-deployments-using-capistrano

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify the code with your favourite editor(vim/emacs/Sublime Text...) or IDE like Rubymine, save the change,
2. Refresh your webpage, your modification should take effect.

Comment: Don't we need to restart web server or touch tmp/restart.txt?